# What is the best way to add logging to static methods in utility classes?

Tags: php, static-methods, log4php

I am trying to figure out the best way to add logging to my static methods in utility classes.  I am using log4php for logging.  What I would like to do is:

```
<?php
require_once  WEBSITE_BASE_DIR . "/log4php/Logger.php";

class TestUtil
{
    private static $log = Logger::getLogger( "testutil" );

    public static function utilMethod1()
    {
        self::$log->trace("Entering utilMethod1");

        // ... do stuff ...

        self::$log->trace("Exiting utilMethod1");
    }

    public static function utilMethod2()
    {
        self::$log->trace("Entering utilMethod2");

        // ... do stuff ...

        self::$log->trace("Exiting utilMethod2");
    }
}
```

However, I can't do this in PHP and get a syntax error on the initialization of the `$log` static variable.  The only way that I can figure out how to do this is to add an `init()` call to every static method:

```
<?php
require_once  WEBSITE_BASE_DIR . "/log4php/Logger.php";

class TestUtil
{
    private static $log = NULL;

    private static function init()
    {
        if (self::$log == NULL)
        {
            self::$log = Logger::getLogger( "testutil" );
        }
    }

    public static function utilMethod1()
    {
        self::init();
        self::$log->trace("Entering utilMethod1");

        // ... do stuff ...

        self::$log->trace("Exiting utilMethod1");
    }

    public static function utilMethod2()
    {
        self::init();
        self::$log->trace("Entering utilMethod2");

        // ... do stuff ...

        self::$log->trace("Exiting utilMethod2");
    }
}
```

But this seems like an excessive amount of redundant code, giving that I have many utility classes with many static methods.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using static methods for everything?

Comment: I am not using static methods for everything.  Just as a way of grouping procedural functions together.  If the application suits an object with associated methods, then I use non-static methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a static method that defines the logger.  You can call this once when you are starting your application.

```
public static function setLogger(LogInterface $logger)
{
    self::$log = $logger;
}
```

A second thing you could do is have a static method that returns the logger instance instead of using a static property.

```
private static function log()
{
    return Logger::getLogger( "testutil" );
}
```

Then instead of calling `self::$log->trace()`, you would just call `self::log()->trace()`.

Comment: For the first suggestion, I could see initializing all the utility classes when the web application starts up.  I already do this to set the WEBSITE_BASE_DIR constant and initialize the log4php configuration parameters.  However, I still would need to do this for each utility class.  Your second suggestion is clever, in that I don't need to do any preparation, I only need to change the way I call it.  The only downside is my logging code will be different from class objects with non-static methods, but I can live with that.

Comment: The first method with an interface really is the best way to handle this in a large application as you're abstracting the dependency.  A DI container can useful for only having to define the dependency once across an entire application.

Comment: Yeah, good point.  I was thinking that since the `Logger` class is already a singleton it wouldn't really make any difference.